# Is there a better way to join these tables in ActiveRecord from bottom to top relation?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

> Author has_many Books
>
> Books has_many Content

If I want to find some duplicate section , for example: "interest"  , in all books and all authors . And I would also like to see their book.title  and author.name.

```
content_section = Content.where(:section  => "interest").select("book_id, section ";

books = Books.where(:id => content_section.map(&:book_id)).select("author_id, title")

authors = Author.where(:id => books.map(&:author_id)).select("name")
```

- Question1:  Is there a better way to achieve this ? ( in performance issue or some others )
- Question2:  Is there a way to make content_section, books, and authors  to merge into a table ? (in ruby side or MySQL side.)
- Question3: what is  content_section.map(&:book_id) means?  I wonder the means of   &:book_id

for example, this SQL(MySQL) will make a big table , so I don't need to merge all result in ruby. And it's easier for me to iterate in views template. But it's performance is very low since joined three table.

```
select * from authors, books, contents 

where authors.id = books.author_id and books.id = content.book_id and content.section = "interest"
```

Any comment is appreciated. Thanks.

> ** update **

after referenced: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978965/rails-how-do-i-build-an-active-relation-scope-to-traverse-many-tables) and [enter link description here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

I try to add model :

> class Author
>
> > has_many: content , :through => book
>
> end

then I tried this in console:

> author.joins( :content ).where(:section => "interest").select("name, title, section:);

I get a SQL :

> select name, title, section from author inner join books on ....  inner join on content .......

- Is this ok ? thanks.

Comment: The performancd of that query (or its activerecord equivalent) will depend on what indexes you have on those tables. What indexes do you have?

Comment: Now I've already added 'section' index.  But I can add all index just if needed. thanks.

Comment: Also worth checking the output of explain to see what your query is doing

Comment: [answer to Q3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1217114/1232102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it:

```
class Author
  has_many :books
  has_many :contents, :through => :books

  scope :by_section, lambda { |section| joins(:contents).where('contents.section' => section) }
end
```

Then you can call:

```
authors = Author.by_section("interest")
```

Also, you were wondering about `content_sections.map(&:book_id)`. That's shorthand for `content_sections.map { |content_section| section.book_id }` which results in an array of book ids.